# Flutter failed to connect. Error socket io timeout

Tags: flutter, websocket, socket.io

Anyone can help find out why socket io failed to connect with an error timeout.
So this fails to connect any WebSocket URL with the same error timeout.
Here is my code so far.

```
class MainWebSocket {
  final _serverUrl =
      'ws://192.168.100.79:6001/app/5453b130999fc928c13ajsusi**ysu'; // Replace with your actual WebSocket URL
  late IO.Socket? socket;
  late String _authToken;
  late String _channelName;
  late String _eventName;
  final ErrorProvider _errorNotifier = ErrorProvider();

  MainWebSocket(String channelName, String eventName) {
    _channelName = channelName;
    _eventName = eventName;
    initializeWebSocket();
    connectWhenInternetAvailable();
  }

  initializeWebSocket() async {
    _authToken = (await Auth.getUserToken())!;

    final authOptions = {
      'auth': {
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $_authToken',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss'],
      },
      'encrypted': false,
      'forceTLS': false,
      'key': "5453b130999fc928c13ajsusi**ysu",
      'namespace': "App.Events",
      'wsHost': "192.168.100.79",
      'wsPort': 6001,
    };

    socket = IO.io(
      _serverUrl,
      IO.OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .setPath('App.Events') // Set the correct path
          .setTimeout(5000)
          .enableMultiplex()
          .setAuth(authOptions)
          .setExtraHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $_authToken',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          })
          .build(),
    );

    socket?.onConnect((_) {
      print('Connected');
      subscribeToChannel();
    });

    socket?.onConnectError((error) {
      print('Connect Error: $error');
    });

    socket?.on('connect_error', (error) {
      print('Connection Error: $error');
    });


    socket?.connect();
  }

  Future<bool> checkInternet() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }
  //*connectWhenInternetAvailable*
  Future<void> connectWhenInternetAvailable() async {
    try {
      bool isConnected = await checkInternet();
      if (isConnected) {
        await socket?.connect();
      } else {
        print('No internet connection. WebSocket not connected.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error connecting to WebSocket: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> subscribeToChannel() async {
    // Subscribe to the specified channel
    socket?.emit('subscribe', [_channelName]);
    print(socket.toString());
    // authenticateUser();
    // Listen to the specified event
    socket?.on(_eventName, (data) {
      print('$_eventName: $data');
      // Handle the event data
    });
  }

  Future<String?> getToken() async {
    return await Auth.getUserToken();
  }

  ///Authentication
  Future<void> authenticateUser(socketId, String channelName) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await CallApi().broadcastAuth({
        'socket_id': socketId,
        'channel_name': channelName, // Pass channelName as a parameter
        'encrypted': true,
        'forceTLS': true,
        'key': '',
        'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss'],
        'namespace': "App.Events",
        'wsHost': LienskillDomainName.lienskillCom,
        'wsPort': 6001,
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Authentication successful
        print('Authentication successful');
      } else if (response.statusCode == 302) {
        // Authentication failed
        _errorNotifier.setError('Authentication failed');
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      // Handle authentication error
      _errorNotifier.setError('Authentication error: $e');
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    socket?.disconnect();
  }
}
```

This URL ws://192.168.100.79:6001/app/5453b130999fc928c13ajsusi**ysu works  best even from postname WebSocket

Hello guys. Anyone can help find out why socket io failed to connect with an error timeout.
So this fails to connect any WebSocket URL with the same error timeout.
Here is my code so far.

```
class MainWebSocket {
  final _serverUrl =
      'ws://192.168.100.79:6001/app/5453b130999fc928c13ajsusi**ysu'; // Replace with your actual WebSocket URL
  late IO.Socket? socket;
  late String _authToken;
  late String _channelName;
  late String _eventName;
  final ErrorProvider _errorNotifier = ErrorProvider();

  MainWebSocket(String channelName, String eventName) {
    _channelName = channelName;
    _eventName = eventName;
    initializeWebSocket();
    connectWhenInternetAvailable();
  }

  initializeWebSocket() async {
    _authToken = (await Auth.getUserToken())!;

    final authOptions = {
      'auth': {
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $_authToken',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss'],
      },
      'encrypted': false,
      'forceTLS': false,
      'key': "5453b130999fc928c13ajsusi**ysu",
      'namespace': "App.Events",
      'wsHost': "192.168.100.79",
      'wsPort': 6001,
    };

    socket = IO.io(
      _serverUrl,
      IO.OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .setPath('App.Events') // Set the correct path
          .setTimeout(5000)
          .enableMultiplex()
          .setAuth(authOptions)
          .setExtraHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $_authToken',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          })
          .build(),
    );

    socket?.onConnect((_) {
      print('Connected');
      subscribeToChannel();
    });

    socket?.onConnectError((error) {
      print('Connect Error: $error');
    });

    socket?.on('connect_error', (error) {
      print('Connection Error: $error');
    });


    socket?.connect();
  }

  Future<bool> checkInternet() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }
  //*connectWhenInternetAvailable*
  Future<void> connectWhenInternetAvailable() async {
    try {
      bool isConnected = await checkInternet();
      if (isConnected) {
        await socket?.connect();
      } else {
        print('No internet connection. WebSocket not connected.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error connecting to WebSocket: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> subscribeToChannel() async {
    // Subscribe to the specified channel
    socket?.emit('subscribe', [_channelName]);
    print(socket.toString());
    // authenticateUser();
    // Listen to the specified event
    socket?.on(_eventName, (data) {
      print('$_eventName: $data');
      // Handle the event data
    });
  }

  Future<String?> getToken() async {
    return await Auth.getUserToken();
  }

  ///Authentication
  Future<void> authenticateUser(socketId, String channelName) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await CallApi().broadcastAuth({
        'socket_id': socketId,
        'channel_name': channelName, // Pass channelName as a parameter
        'encrypted': true,
        'forceTLS': true,
        'key': '',
        'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss'],
        'namespace': "App.Events",
        'wsHost': LienskillDomainName.lienskillCom,
        'wsPort': 6001,
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Authentication successful
        print('Authentication successful');
      } else if (response.statusCode == 302) {
        // Authentication failed
        _errorNotifier.setError('Authentication failed');
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      // Handle authentication error
      _errorNotifier.setError('Authentication error: $e');
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    socket?.disconnect();
  }
}
```

This URL ws://192.168.100.79:6001/app/5453b130999fc928c13ajsusi**ysu works  best even from postname WebSocket

Comment: Try using 10.0.2.2 instance of 192.168.100.79